# Object received from springboot backend and resent back has fields containing null values

Tags: java, json, angular, spring-boot

I use an angular+springboot web application in which an object ( for this example- clinic object ) fetched from springboot in angular is **not** modified, and then is sent back to springboot, and some of its prperties's values for no apparent reason just become null, and others ( a boolean property get value of false, and integer properties get value of 0 ) get default values.

This is a table in which clinic objects are desplayed, and from which a modal to update a clinic is opened.

```
                <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;"></th>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">State</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Foundation Year</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Supervisor</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Clinic Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr [ngClass]="{'not-active-clinic':!clinic.active}" *ngFor="let clinic of clinics">
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                            <button class="btn-primary mr-1" (click)="openEditModal(editModal,clinic)"><i
                                    class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <!--Edit Modal -->
                            <ng-template #editModal let-modal>
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Clinic Edit</h4>
                                    <button style="margin-left: 0;" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"
                                        (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form dir="rtl">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-3">
                                                <label>
                                                    Clinic Name: </label>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-9">
                                                <input style="width: 100%;" type="text" name="clinicName"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="edittedClinic.clinicName">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-3">
                                                <label>
                                                    Supervisor</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-9">
                                                <select (change)="onChange()" style="width: 100%;"
                                                    name="clinicalSupervisorId"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="edittedClinic.clinicalSupervisorId">
                                                    <option *ngFor="let s of supervisors" [value]="s.id">
                                                        {{s.firstName+' '+s.lastName}}
                                                    </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-3">
                                                <label>
                                                    description:</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-9">
                                                <textarea style="width: 100%;height:350px"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="edittedClinic.description" name="description">

                                                </textarea>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark"
                                        (click)="modal.close('Save click');onEdit(clinic)">Edit</button>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>


                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-delete-account"
                                (click)="openDeleteModal(deleteModal)">
                                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"><i
                                        class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                            </button>
                            <!--Delete Modal -->
                            
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                            <button (click)="onChangeClinicState(clinic)">
                                {{clinic.active?"Add To Archive":"Restore"}}</button>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">{{clinic.yearFounded}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">{{clinic.clinicalSupervisorId}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:right;">{{clinic.clinicName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This the method in angular to fetch the edited object to send it to service in which there is the http call to send the clinic object to springboot:

```
onEdit(clinicToEdit:Clinic)
{

this.dashboardService.updateClinicDetails(this.edittedClinic).subscribe(
  data=>{
    clinicToEdit=Object.create(this.edittedClinic);
  },
  err=>{
    
  }
)
    
}
```

This is the method in the service to send the http put call

```
  updateClinicDetails(clinic:Clinic)
```

{

```
return this.http.put(BASE_URL +`/api/v1/clinic/${clinic.clinicName}`,clinic);
```

}

This is the API method in springboot to get the clinic object sent from angular.

```
@PutMapping(path = "{clinicName}")
public int updateClinicById(@PathVariable("clinicName") String clinicName, @RequestBody Clinic clinicToUpdate)
{
    return clinicService.updateClinic(clinicName, clinicToUpdate);
}
```

This is the constructor of clinic object invoked in order to fetch the JSON sent to springboot from angular.

```
    public Clinic(@JsonProperty("clinicName") String clinicName,
        @JsonProperty("clinicalSupervisorId") int clinicalSupervisorId,
        @JsonProperty("description") String description, @JsonProperty("yearFounded") int yearFounded,
        @JsonProperty("active") boolean active)
{
    this.clinicName = clinicName;
    this.clinicalSupervisorId = clinicalSupervisorId;
    this.yearFounded = yearFounded;
    this.description = description;
    this.active = active;
}
```

Now, the thing is when modified, those mentioned properties don't contain null values, or their default values, What is the explanation to this, and what's the best way to solve it?

Comment: You see them in angular as not modified. But you see them as console.log which means a string representation. Share with us your angular code. Something is malformed for sure there.

Comment: @Boug I added some code